# NodeJS Try-Catch not blocking

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When the JSON.parse() fails, it should be caught and res.end() should terminate the client request. But the for-loop is still somehow executed, causing a TypeError. Why does it reach that point? It's as if the try-catch block is async, hence the title.

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    var options = {
        host: 'www.example.com'
    };

    var i = 0
    while (i < 5){
        i++;
        http.get(options, function(resp) {
            var body = '';
            resp.on('data', function(chunk) {
                body += chunk;
            });

            resp.on('end', function() {

                try{
                    var j = JSON.parse(body); // Body will ocasionally be non-json
                }catch(e){
                    res.end("JSON couldn't parse body"); // This should terminate the main request
                }

                for(let item of j.list){
                    console.log(item); // This block sholdn't execute if try-catch fails
                }

            });
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: `This block sholdn't execute if try-catch fails` put it inside the try block then ... or `return res.end("JSON couldn't parse body");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...

```
try{
  var j = JSON.parse(body); // Body will ocasionally be non-json
}catch(e){
    res.end("JSON couldn't parse body"); // This should terminate the main request
    return; // <<<<<
}
```

...

Answer (score 0):

If the JSON.parse(body) throw exception, you also need to catch the  exception of the for loop of j.list, put it in the try block:

```
        resp.on('end', function() {

            try{
                var j = JSON.parse(body); // Body will ocasionally be non-json
                for(let item of j.list){
                    console.log(item); // This block sholdn't execute if try-catch fails
                }
            }catch(e){
                res.end("JSON couldn't parse body"); // This should terminate the main request
            }


        });
```